# Do API controllers work when launching with IIS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm currently building an ASP.NET Core app, and up until now haven't used controllers since everything was managed by a SignalR hub.
I have decided to add an API controller (with the attribute) in order to handle API requests from the client, such as fetching from the database.
Here is my API controller:

```
 [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class BaseApiController : ControllerBase
    {

        private IMediator _mediator;

        protected IMediator Mediator => _mediator ??= HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IMediator>();
    }
```

And here is the Messages controller which derives from API controller:

```
public class MessagesController : BaseApiController
    {
        private readonly DataContext _context;

        public MessagesController(DataContext dataContext)
        {
            _context = dataContext;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<List<Message>>> GetMessages() =>
            await Mediator.Send(new List.Query());

    }
```

For some reason, when sending a request from the client side I get a 404. I think, that it happens because of some sort of "clash" between the API and the IIS launch. Sorry if this may sound stupid, I'm new.

If launching the project with an API controller via IIS isn't a problem, then I'll look elsewhere.

Comment: Before hosting the application on IIS, whether the application works well in the local environment? Besides, for the "net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET" error, can your share the detailed error message? And, please check the request url, perhaps the application was configured to use https request, but the current request url is a http request. So, it will show the net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error. If that is the case, you could change the request url from `http` to `https`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Startup.cs you need to add the following code to `ConfigureServices()`

```
services.AddControllers();
```

and to `Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)`

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    ...
});
```

Comment: Hey, you're right and I forgot to add the bottom part. After adding it, it works if I try from the API, but the client side (built on js and axios) is refusing and giving me an net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context